# rmse of differenced vs undifferenced data

Tags: forecasting, rms

if I created a forecast on a differenced data set and compared that to the differenced holdout set, would this rmse be the same as if I reverted back to the undifferenced data and then performed the rmse?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out and the answer is no, they are not the same. They are related by a constant in my case but I'm not sure if that is a generality.